# Booking System Excel - ignoring 1st and last time IF statement condition met

Tags: vba, excel, loops

What i need is for the code below to ignore the first and last time the conditions are met in the IF statement.

Appreciate the feedback.

```
Do

    Set aCell = orange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

    If aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <= Dt.Value And aCell.Offset(0, 3).Value >= Dt.Value Then
        Set Cl = aCell.Cells(1, 5)
        Set Nn = aCell.Cells(1, 10)
        Set ID = aCell.Offset(0, -1)

        If oCell <> Nn Or iCell <> ID Then
           dCell.Value = Nn
           Set oCell = Nn
           Set iCell = ID
       End If
```

Comment: Doesn't allow? What happens? Is there an error? (You would need to comment out the On Error Resume Next etc... ) . Your example should be [Minimal, Verifiable and Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) meaning that the video link might be useful as additional info but shouldn't be a requirement to answering your question.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. You have lots of If statements and Loops and a Select statement. Properly indenting you code, leaving some appropriate breathing space in the code (i.e. lines not always on top of each other), and removing unneccessary comments will make this question much more appealing to answer. Also, consider if all the code is actually necessary in the post.

Comment: modifying existing code that works, is outside of the purpose of this website.  ... however, if you modify the code yourself and get errors or undesirable results, then we will be more than happy to try to help you  ... and yes, please correct the indentation before posting your attempt.

Comment: i looked at the video. there is more than "part3" and there is a lot more code than what you posted. ... your request is not a simple one. i suggest that either you hire a programmer or you go through the tutorial a number of times until you understand how the code works, then make the necessary changes yourself ... what you want is to have each booking start in the afternoon and end in the morning.

Comment: Thanks for input, have not been working a lot with code, so appologies for not presenting the case propably. Please see amended question.

Comment: Good that you edited but does the edit meet the requirements of minimal, verifiable and complete as in the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Also, you say in the If statement. You have two. Which do you mean?

Comment: You might consider some code that finds all the matches for the conditions first and then rest of your loop code which would include  a counter. And ensure you include enough code so people know how your loop is ending..